# Create "new instance of object" method in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create an instance of a class, from that class, without using templates?
I need to do somethink like 
`static classobj* classobj::create (){return new this;}`

Now I use class template and pass to template type of creatable class like :

```
template<class T>
class basic_class  {
   public:
   static T *create(int param) { return new T(param); }
}
```

and

```
class A : public basic_class<A> {}
```

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this without using templates?

Comment: I think we need to get a better of idea of what exactly you mean with "from that class". At compile time, the class is already there. At run time, there are no class objects (in contrast to e.g. Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you have to add static create to every class:

```
class A
{
public:
  //to create
  static A* create(int param) { return new A(param); }
};
```

and then do this:

```
A* ptr = A::create(4);
```

or better, avoiding memory leaks

```
std::unique_ptr<A> uptr(A::create(4));
```

Or, if your issue is to make a "smart" create in the basic_class for any constructor, then do this in C++11:

```
template <class T>
class base_class
{
public:
  template<typename... Params>
  static T* construct(Params&&... parameters) { return new T(std::forward<Params>(parameters)...); }
};

class A : public base_class<A>
{
public:
  A(const std::string& s) {}
  A(int i) {}
};
```

and so

```
A::create(std::string("Hey"));
A::create(5);
```

both work now.

**Edit:** Base class defines "construct" method. So the above should be

```
A::construct(std::string("Hey"));
A::construct(5);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not this?

```
return new classobj;
```

Or this:

```
return new decltype(*this);
```

But please don't do this at all. The pointer returned by your function has unclear ownership semantics. We generally don't need raw pointers nowadays.

Comment: Yes, of course! I simplified example for easier perception.
Is second solution will work for inheritors of class? Is this method will create class obj that will define that function or it inheritor?

Comment: And which signature of method should be?

Comment: And how combine that with "static" ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a non-template class like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
  static (Magic)* create() { return new (Magic); }
}
```

We would then call this method thusly:

```
class Derived : public Base {};

Derived* object = Derived::create();
```

And the question is: what incantation do we substitute for "(Magic)?"  Unfortunately, there is no such syntax.  Static class methods are just like regular functions.  All types involved must be known at the point the function is declared.

Can you elaborate on why you don't want to use templates?  Perhaps there's another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a copy constructor first

```
 classobj(const classobj& obj);
```

then

```
 return new classobj(*this)
```